# Use IF Statement With #N/A?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

Currently have a macro with a lot of If statments which goes through each row and tests for certain conditions. One of the conditions which needs to be added to every if statement is the following: If c1 (which I have Dim'd as a range) = "#N/A"). After asking a few people, I finally got the correct line of code to add before each of my if statements as another condition it is:

```
  If CVErr(cl.Value) = CVErr(xlErrNA) And
```

Unfortunately this keeps messing up when the cl.Value was something NOT "#N/A". I wanted to see if there was a way to maybe start off the macro such as Do While or something that starts it off by testing to see if cl.Value is "#N/A" and if it is go through all the other IF statements and if not go to the next cell. Please advise. Thanks for your help.

Here is just a quick example/peek at 4 If statements which I have added the above line which tests for "#N/A" which brings up the error (Says 13: type mismatch).

```
For Each cl In range("A2", range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp))


 If CVErr(cl.Value) = CVErr(xlErrNA) And _
 cl.Offset(, 11).Value = "Bond Deals" And cl.Offset(, 2).Value Like "*CLO*" Then
        cl.Value = "CLO"
 End If

 If CVErr(cl.Value) = CVErr(xlErrNA) And cl.Offset(, 11).Value = "Bond Deals" And cl.Offset(, 12).Value Like "BCC*" Then
        c1.Value = "CLO"
 End If

 If CVErr(cl.Value) = CVErr(xlErrNA) And _
 cl.Offset(, 11).Value = "Bond Deals" And cl.Offset(, 14).Value Like "*CLO*" Then
        c1.Value = "CLO"
 End If

 If CVErr(cl.Value) = CVErr(xlErrNA) And _
 cl.Offset(, 11).Value = "Bond Deals" And cl.Offset(, 15).Value Like "*CLO*" Then
        c1.Value = "CLO"
 End If
```

Answer (score 1):

`#N/A` is a special error value in the worksheet, not a string.

You can test for it with the following:

```
If WorksheetFunction.Iserror(cl.Offset(0, 0).Value) ...
```

That will return TRUE for any error. If you want to test specifically for `#N/A`, do the same thing with the function ISNA(...).

Regarding your revised question, if I am understanding correctly, why couldn't enclose your other IFs in the NA IF?

```
For ...
    If (CVErr(cl..Value)  eq CVErr(xlErrNA) Then
        If .... Then
            do_something
        End If
        If .... Then
            do_another_thing
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Please note that the **eq** on the second line of the code sketch should be the equal sign. Am writing this on my phone, which doesn't have that key :(

Comment: It can be done this way `If CVErr(cl.Value) = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then` but there is no significant difference.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. I tried adding this before each If statement and realized it wouldn't work when the cl.Value was something NOT "#N/A". I wanted to see if there was a way to maybe start off the macro such as Do While or something that starts it off by testing to see if cl.Value is "#N/A" and if it is go through all the other IF statements and if not go to the next cell. Please advise. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Edited OP to include new problem.

Comment: @AniLulla, I think the easiest way to do what you want is to keep the `FOR` loop you have and then begin the loop with an `IF` statement that tests for the error condition. If it finds the error, then go on and do what you were doing with the `IFs`; if the encompassing `IF` does not find an error, then it takes you down to the `NEXT` and the loop starts up again with the next cell. I added to my answer with a sketch of this idea a couple of days ago - couldn't be more specific as I did this on my phone since my Internet was out!